# LoadError - Unable to autoload constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I get the below error **quite often** only in the development environment. I try to google a couple of solution but nothing works for me. And I believe I am already following the naming convention. Can someone have a look on it

```
LoadError - Unable to autoload constant Payments::PromoCode, expected /home/aniket/my_project/app/models/payments/promo_code.rb to define it:
  app/models/ability.rb:649:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:245:in `user_info'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:239:in `user_list'
  app/middleware/skip_trackable.rb:8:in `call'
```

*File* `promo_code.rb`

```
module Payments
  class PromoCode < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_settings
    has_many :users, through: :user_settings

    enum type: %w(value distinction)

    validates :type, inclusion: { in: Payments::PromoCode::type.keys}, allow_blank: true
  end
end
```

Ability

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user, session = nil)
    can :manage, Payments::PromoCode
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you have in `/home/aniket/my_project/app/models/payments/promo_code.rb`?

Comment: @mrzasa Some association, validations, enum, callbacks and few methods

Comment: Could you paste first few lines of this file? Namely the ones defining the modules and class.

Comment: @mrzasa I have updated some of the things

Comment: no idea, it's quite strange

Comment: Do you mean that the `promo_code.rb` file you posted exists at `/home/aniket/my_project/app/models/payments/promo_code.rb` ?

Comment: Yes it does exist

Comment: you sure you place the file `promo_code.rb` in the folder `app/models/payments/`?

Comment: Try running `spring stop` and the restarting the rails server / console. I find that the autoloader sometimes get stuck and causes strange constant missing errors. Especially if the folder was created after the server was started.

Comment: @DieuLinh I am 100% positive